# Pros and cons of using Guava RateLimiter vs resilience4j ratelimiter

Tags: guava, rate-limiting, resilience4j

We are thinking of implementing a rate limiter in one of our java based services. Wanted to understand the pros and cons of using Guava ratelimiter vs resilience4j ratelimiter.

Haven't worked on them before and was not able to find any good articles describing the differences between the two. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question.

Guava rate limiter is still BETA for some reason. Do check if resilience4J's rate limiter also equally distributes the calls in the given time window before sending them, since guava one does distribution of the calls (Do thoroughly test this feature so that spike TPS are smoothened out).